# setup CallbackURl of Twitter in Sharekit for iphone !

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

How can i avoid callbackURL in sharekit to post on twitter ? Any other way to implement twitter sharing ?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to mention a callback URL since it is mandatory in twitter. But it will be only a placeholder and completely ignored.

Its more explained in here:
[iOS: ShareKit >> Twitter Settings >> Callback URL --- What is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760195/ios-sharekit-twitter-settings-callback-url-what-is-it)

and the reason caused to have it is explained here:
http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-api-announce/browse_frm/thread/2086c8c5a12242ec?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid callbackURL. If you are using sharekit, the callbackURL will not be used. But its mandatory field. You can give URL of some search engine.

Comment: The callbackURL specified in code should be same as one specified while creating appid in twitter.

Comment: but i have not created any URL .. and check out my question i want to avoid it ..